# ASP.NET 4 Health Monitoring - capture User Agent Details

Tags: asp.net, health-monitoring

I am currently implementing **Health monitoring** on my ASP.Net Web forms .NET 4.

It gives me below sections of details when there is an un-handled exception on my site.

1. Summary
2. Application Information
3. Events
4. Process information:
5. Exception information:
6. Request information: Thread information:

I would like to also capture **user agent details**. is it possible?
Can any one point me to the right source on how to achieve this?
Also interested to know how can i capture this exception details in to my database, if the exception is not from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found this on msdn, hope any one in need will get benifited with these links.

1. How to store events to SQL Server
2. How to forward events to WMI
3. How to forward events to e-mail
4. Custom Failure Audit Default at 
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.webfailureauditevent(v=vs.100).aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893664